# Generating PDF files dynamically in servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf-generation

Is there any way to create PDF dynamically against receiving texts and images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) and [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports) are great to create pdf reports via Java.

With [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) you can easily create the jasper files needed for this. Very easy to use tool and helped me a lot when I needed to create some pdf reports.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) library.

If you're generating reports then [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports) can generate PDF output.

Answer (score 3):

We use [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//).

Comment: Flying Saucer...Is it a modified form of ITEXT

Comment: @Biju: Flying Saucer is not *modified* iText at all.  You can read their web site to see that they are an XHTML rendering engine that makes it very easy to create PDF's from XHTML.

Comment: Flying Saucer provides option to convert xhtml to pdf using iText.

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries for working with PDF in Java, for example [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) and [Apache PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of ways to generate PDFs on the fly.

In Java, you can use [the iText library](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-javapdf/).  If you wanted to use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), you could use [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) and possibly [rst2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/).  Or you could just generate [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/) files on the fly and make a system call to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I work with [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/quickstartguide.html) and it works amazingly well. It's well supported and it's based on the [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) standard.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe useful to other searchers.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) can populate templates and produce documents on the fly.  Assuming you mean you need to include images and text, Docmosis can populate these on the fly from Java objects, text/image files, database queries etc.  Java and Openoffice are required server-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing reports based on for example SQL queries then iReport is a good choice although it's sometimes a bit heavyweight. On the other hand if you're going to produce something that's more about presentation and design, like a product sheet or a brochure then my experience is that it's alot easier to first generate html and css and then use it to generate a PDF.